# Not so fast! (fastcgi/fcgi as synonyms)

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, synonym-request

The first word in the [description for the tag fcgi](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fcgi/info) is "FastCGI". "FastCGI" occurs another eight times in the description. I might not have a score of 5 in either tag, but I still think this synonym is a no-brainer. Could someone with the required score please suggest [fcgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fcgi) as a synonym for [fastcgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastcgi)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fcgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fcgi) -> [fastcgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastcgi) is merged and syn'd.